# How to stop AjaxControlToolkit.ModalPopupExtender from reloading the page when the popup is closed

Tags: vb.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

We have a website written in ASP.Net/VB.Net, and at the bottom of one page we have this code:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="upnlMessage" runat="server" UpdateMode="Always">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:HiddenField ID="hidVerified" runat="server" />
        <asp:HiddenField ID="hidRefund" runat="server" />
        <!--this button is used as dummy TargetControlID for the ModalPopupExtenders which opened programmatically from code behind -->
        <asp:Button ID="btnHiddenModal" CausesValidation="false" runat="server" Style="display: none;" />
        <cc1:ModalPopupExtender ID="mpeMessage"
            runat="server"
            PopupControlID="pnlMessage"
            BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground"
            TargetControlID="btnHiddenModal"
            DropShadow="False"
            Y="50"
            RepositionMode="RepositionOnWindowResize"
            BehaviorID="btnClose">
        </cc1:ModalPopupExtender>
        <asp:PlaceHolder ID="plhMessage" runat="server">
            <asp:Panel ID="pnlMessage" CssClass="message" runat="server">
                <asp:Panel ID="pnlConfirmMessageImage" runat="server" CssClass="messageImage infoImage"></asp:Panel>
                <asp:Panel ID="pnlConfirmMessageHeader" runat="server" CssClass="messageHeader infoHeader">
                    <asp:Label ID="lblConfirmMessageHeader" Text="Information" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                </asp:Panel>
                <div class="messageBody">
                    <asp:Label ID="lblConfirmMessageText" Text="" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                </div>
                <div class="messageFooter">
                    <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnCloseMessage" CssClass="SubButton" Text="OK" OnClick="btnCloseMessage_Click" CausesValidation="false" />
                </div>
            </asp:Panel>
        </asp:PlaceHolder>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

When the page loads we do some checks, and if necessary use the popup to display a warning message. The popup is diplayed like this:

```
mpeMessage.Show()
```

When we click the close button on the popup the page reloads which causes a validation error. Surely there is a way to close the popup without reloading the page? The code for btnClose looks like this:

```
<input class="SubButton" id="btnClose" onclick="<%= $"closeAndRefresh('{[Global].GetUrlCloseAndRefresh(m_strRecordNumber)}');" %>" type="button" value="<%= m_strCloseLabel %>" name="btnClose" />
```

btnCloseMessage_Click contains this code:

```
mpeMessage.Hide()
```

Can anyone help me with this? It seems like it should be simple but nothing I've tried so far has made any difference. All I know is if I don't display the popup the page loads successfully, but if I do I get a validation error when the popup is closed. Thanks

Comment: I found a way to stop the validation error without needing to stop the page reloading. The error was occurring because certain text fields contained html tags. I removed the name attributes from the those fields, as they are only used for display anyway, and that stopped them being submitted, and therefore validated. I'm sure there will be people who could still use a solution to this question so I'll leave it open for now, since I haven't really answered it.

Answer (score 0):

there are 2 ways to let the ajax popup dialog close.

You can allow/have (or shall I say suffer) a page post-back on that button click. Since a post-back will cause a browser round trip, then when the server returns a fresh new copy of the browser, then of course any popup will collapse due to the new page being rendered.

However, if you don't want a post-back, then you need/want to use a client-side JavaScript routine, and when you click on that button, then you run client-side code to close the popup dialog.

So, have the button in the pop dialog call this JavaScript routine:

```
      <Button id="searchCancel"  
          class="burkebutt"
          onclick="MyClearPop();return false;" ><span aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-times fa-lg">&nbsp;Cancel</span>
      </Button>



function MyClearPop() {
        $('#c2').hidePopup();
        return false;
```

So, using hidePopup() should work.

I now using the jQuery.UI dialog, and I find it more flexible then the aj toolkit one, but looking at some old code, .hidePopup() looks to be how you can close a popup dialog from the aj toolkit.

My older code did not have a "#" for some reason, and that older code was this:

```
function MyClearPop() {
        $find('c2').hidePopup();
        return false;
```

So, perhaps using $find('c2') without a "#" will work. In this example, "c2" was the target control id of the popup.